# Trying to understanding node createServer callback

Tags: node.js

Using the Node.js hello world example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I'm trying to find where createServer within http.js "looks for" a function and then passes it two objects (which above are named 'req' and 'res'.  I've searched through http.js and the only thing I found was:

```
exports.createServer = function(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
};
```

Does that mean the anonymous function:

```
function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}
```

...is passed as 'requestListener' and...

```
return new Server(requestListener);
```

...is where the req and res objects get passed back?

Comment: Actually `requestListener` gets called when 'request' events are emitted on the Server object. See locations of `.emit('request'` near [line 2017 of `http.js`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L2017)

Comment: @Dan D. so does that mean that emit passes the req and res to the anonymous function when the server gets a request?

Comment: Yes, via EventEmitter pattern. As in the Server constructor it has `this.addListener('request', requestListener);` which `.emit` routes the `.emit('request', req, res);` internally `.emit` uses the list of listeners for an event in this case `'request'` and does the equivalent of calling the listeners with the passed arguments.

Comment: @JohnGalt, another question, what exactly type are req and res in the callback. I can't find them in the doc

Comment: Hi jason, req and res or just objects...To see everything they contain just log them console.log(req).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Javascript functions themselves are "values" you can assign to "objects". Since you can pass an object to another function, then you may pass a function itself as an object.

`requestListener` is the parameter `createServer` named as `requestListener` that is being used to call the `Server` `constructor` with it.

You can also see this in ruby, where you can call a function and at the same time pass it the code to be executed in a do block, as a parameter.